# Recommended BIOS for MSI Z68A-GD55 and GeForce GTX 970

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios

After a video card failure, I recently upgraded to a GeForce GTX 970, MSI Chipset.  The motherboard I have for this is an MSI Z68A-GD55.

However, on POST, the behavior of the computer has changed.  I used to get a splash screen from the BIOS, and the option to get into the setup.  As expected.  Now, I simply get a blank screen with "A2" or "B2" in the corner.  The beep code has also changed.  I now get the one long beep that indicates a good startup, but I also get 3 short, happy chirps, about 15 seconds apart.  After this, the computer boots normally.

There are two problems I am experiencing:
1) The ~45 second delay in startup time.
2) I cannot get into the BIOS setup screen.  Hitting delete to load it simply causes a black screen to load.

I have replaced and rechecked every hardware component in this machine and I am confident all the parts currently in there are good.  On a lark, I checked about interactions between this specific motherboard and video card and found [this topic](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=184774.0).  This seems to imply the problem (a base incompatibility between the BIOS and the graphics card), but the solution prescribed is so confusing I don't know how to go forward.

The topic draws a distinction between ME7 and ME8 BIOSes, but that's not in any terminology I'm familiar with using this motherboard.  My installed BIOS version is N.70.  Neither linked topic from that forum thread seems to shed a lot of light on the situation - one is a benchmark thread that doesn't even mention the BIOS, and the other is a bios beta release thread that has vague and confusing instructions.

Can anyone shed any light on how to go forward in this situation?

Comment: You shouldn't have to update the BIOS to use a graphics card.  The two have nothing to do with one another. If you think it will help install the current revision, since you have a problem, upgrading the BIOS is an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Ramhound The linked topic says otherwise, as do the two problems I enumerated at startup time.  These problems persist even if hard drives are totally disconnected.

Comment: As I said.  Upgrade the firmware to the current release if you think it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I already did.  N.70 is the current stable as suggested on the MSI website.  It simply does not translate to this ME7, ME8, and 25.x versions that are being thrown around in the linked topic.  Hence my confusion.